# How to verify that OWIN generated token coming from user for whom it is generated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, jwt, owin

I am using OWIN to generate the access token which is passed to the user after the successful OTP verification.
My concerns:

1. If client 1 generated a valid token and passing it to me in the subsequent request in the header.
2. If client 2 also generated a valid token and passing it to me in the subsequent request in the header.

   Both clients have a valid token with them with some expiry time.

Now the **Issue** is if client 1 uses client 2 token then also my `[authorize]` attribute will successfully pass the token and sent the response accordingly.

I want this to stop. As only the client for whom the token is generated can only use that. client 2 can't use the client 1.

Thanks

Comment: and how will client 1 obtain client 2's token? The whole point is that the token is a secret to that client. Otherwise you just end up with another token to secure the 1st token, and then go round the circle again.

Comment: It's very useful to avoid packages interception and misuse by malicious tools, for example. +1

Comment: @ADyson Hmm let's assume two guys sitting in a single room both logged in with their own credentials and received an access token in return. In order to get access next time he will send the token along with request. So person one uses person two token and pass it along all the request he can modify headers see the data which is travelling in header using various tools.

Comment: Is the site not running over HTTPS?

Comment: Avoid any chance of interception over the network by using HTTPS. If they're simply looking over each others shoulders...well the site should not be displaying the token anywhere visible in the page or browser bar. If client 2 left their desktop and client 1 went on there to physically steal the token, that's client 2's problem, not yours. I really am failing to see what realistic scenario you are imagining here. Is there any other situation than the one I've just described where you think the token can be stolen? You said "So person one uses person two token" but didn't say how he got it.

Comment: @ADyson sorry i was very ill,
have you heard about Fiddler or Charles proxy? Those softwares are able to inject ssl read this quote 
"Putting a debugging proxy between a client and an HTTPS endpoint won’t work because HTTPS cannot be decrypted by the proxy. Fortunately, Fiddler offers a workaround where it will insert a new certificate in the SSL keychain and use that to fake a certificate for the endpoint Source-https://stackify.com/fiddler-vs-charles/".
That's my worry!

Comment: Read https://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp for the actual detail. 1) It still requires physical access to the targeted user's machine to install and run Fiddler, 2) even if that could be done without the user's knowledge somehow, their site would show a certificate warning which should alert them. And like I said, if the user gave someone else physical access to the machine and their logon credentials, that's their problem, not yours.

Comment: Hmmm! Thanks, @ADyson. Thank You!. I implemented JWT as it checked all my boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can do this:

When generating the token for the user get the user ip

```
var ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

Save the IP in a map table, user|ip|token
Now for each request you could validate if the IP belongs to the user by adding a custom Authorize attribute

```
public class CheckIpAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            //here you can go to your map table and validate if the IP 
            //and User match
            return true;
        }
```

This is the only way you can validate what you want, by IP, because you cannot validate User vs Token, because the User belongs to the Token.

Comment: IP addresses of clients frequently change dynamically, and users these days use multiple devices. This approach might "work" from a strictly technical point of view but it won't be long before it starts to royally annoy the users who keep getting locked out, and the helpdesk staff who have to unlock them. In any case, see my comments above - if the site uses SSL and the token is not being sent in the querystring, and it doesn't permanently persist or anything silly like that, then this is really a non-issue. The OP has not given us any valid scenario to be concerned about.

Comment: I agree, however a token in a device and another is different, anyway I just helped with a solution that may work for him and it is the only thing he can do in this case and see if works or not

Comment: "however a token in a device and another is different" That's not so bad. .A token in a browser session and another is different too, though, even though the IP is the same, which could cause a problem. And expired tokens need to be removed periodically. And also persisting the token anywhere else than where it's actually required is arguably a security flaw all of its own.